# On Area51 can we make "Following" not a link and add "Unfollow" as a link below "Share This"?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, area-51

On area51 I just clicked on my own site-proposal "following" link thinking it would show a list of people following the proposal (my fault) and of course it instantly unfollowed my proposal.

Name change or confirmation before unfollowing would be cool. (at least some mouse hover text).  Or, a separate link to "Unfollow" maybe.

Possibly something like the Twitter.com convention I would propose that this link show up under "Share This".

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is starting to be a standard UI, since that's the way Twitter does it. A lot of Twitter users are used to it working that way.

Comment: this should probably be a comment

Comment: Thanks @Joel.

twitter.com convention would be good.  Just checked my Twitter "following" link takes me to a list of users whereas the "Unfollow" [Action] removes me from that person's feed.

Or, are you talking about a different client / UI?

Comment: Joel was talking about the Twitter web UI, like what you proposed.

Comment: Thanks for taking care of this change guys. I appreciate it.